# webpack say UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning to me

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron

I'm using electron and webpack.
When building dev-mode my project.
Node Error appear "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Exited with code 2"
 "DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.".
And Dose not open electron.
I'm checked firewall.

How I setting currently my project?

This is my package.json.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gilkc.png)

```js
{
  "name": "abce",
  "productName": "abce Launcher",
  "version": "0.10.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test node --trace-warnings ./test/runTests.js",
    "test-all": "npm run test && npm run build && npm run test-e2e",
    "test-watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "test-e2e": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test node --trace-warnings ./test/runTests.js e2e",
    "hot-server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --max_old_space_size=4096 server.js",
    "build-main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.electron.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "build-renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.production.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "build-web": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --max_old_space_size=4096 --trace-warnings -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.web.production.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "build": "npm run deploy-content-api && npm run build-main && npm run build-renderer",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production electron ./app/",
    "start-hot": "cross-env HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill ./app/main.development",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "dev": "npm run deploy-content-api && npm run hot-server -- --start-hot",
    "dev-web": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --trace-warnings -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.web.development.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "dev-web-hot": "cross-env START_HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development node --trace-warnings ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.web.development.js",
    "package": "npm run build && build --publish never",
    "package-win": "npm run build && build --win --x64",
    "package-linux": "npm run build && build --linux",
    "package-all": "npm run build && build -mwl",
    "cleanup": "mop -v",
    "deploy-content-api": "cross-env uglifyjs ./content-api/tree-launcher-content.js -c -m -o ./app/public/tree-launcher-content.js",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"**/*.*(js|jsx|ts|tsx)\""
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/internals/mocks/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "app/node_modules"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/test/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testMatch": [
      "**/?(*.)(spec|test).ts?(x)"
    ]
  },
  "build": {
    "productName": "Elif Launcher",
    "appId": "com.visang.fel-launcher",
    "asar": false,
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        },
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "file"
        }
      ]
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/",
      "!dist/**/*.*.map",
      "node_modules/",
      "app.html",
      "main.js",
      "fel.sql",
      "fel.yaml",
      "fel_server.exe",
      "OSKSpawner.exe",
      "static/",
      "public/",
      "package.json",
      "settings.json"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources",
      "output": "release"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "dir"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb",
        "AppImage"
      ]
    }
  },
  "bin": {
    "electron": "./node_modules/.bin/electron"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^2.5.39",
    "@types/history": "^4.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^20.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^15.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.1",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/sinon": "^2.3.1",
    "asar": "^0.13.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-dev-expression": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "boiler-room-custodian": "^0.6.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "css-modules-require-hook": "^4.0.6",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "1.6.7",
    "electron-builder": "^19.8.0",
    "electron-builder-http": "^19.15.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.0.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.6.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint": "^4.6.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-formatter-pretty": "^1.3.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.8.3",
    "eslint-plugin-compat": "^1.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.3.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "sinon": "^3.2.1",
    "spectron": "^3.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "ts-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.1.0",
    "tslint": "5.15.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "tslint-react": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.3",
    "uglify-js": "^3.4.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.13.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.9",
    "babili-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "electron-debug": "^1.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-protobuf": "^3.3.0",
    "grpc": "^1.3.2",
    "history": "^4.6.3",
    "md5-file": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-draggable": "^3.0.5",
    "react-id-swiper": "1.5.7",
    "react-progressbar.js": "^0.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.1",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.0",
    "source-map-support": "~0.4.15",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "winston": "2.4.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^1.4.6"
  },
  "devEngines": {
    "node": ">=6.x",
    "npm": ">=3.x"
  }
}
```